# Dialog Authentication In AAD for Outlook Add-in

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I am investigating how to convert an existing outlook add-in to authenticate to one of our APIs via Azure Active Directory. The way the add-in works, it would severely limit the user experience if they were constantly prompted with a dialog. If I were to base my solution off this [sample project](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins), how often could we expect the user to have to interact with a dialog or login?

Comment: We have documentation about using Single Sign-On with Azure AD v2.0. Can you take a look to see if it answers your questions? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins

Comment: Thanks. So I am guessing that it will behave similar to web apps using AAD SSO since it is using the same auth endpoint. For example we have AAD SSO configured with multiple web apps, and even an android app. If you are signed in to your microsoft account, then the app is able to get the access token without user interaction.

Comment: There is broader documentation on authentication to explore and compare all the options here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/overview-authn-authz What is your auth scenario?